# How can I invoke a function in a controller when I am about to switch to another controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a function which saves all the selected form elements on a page to angular cache (I have a service for it). I want to invoke this function just as I clicked the navigation to go to another page (Which has a different controller). How can I do it?

Comment: You can better save it in a service. And acces it from their. Inject the service in both the controller.

Comment: @Explore-X I already do that. I just need to ability to invoke function on time.

Answer (score 2):

You can do as below.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.factory('MySharingService', function() {
    var tempData = {};
    return {
        saveData: function(data) {
            tempData = data;
        },
       getData: function() {
            return tempData;
        }
    };
});

function First($scope, MySharingService) {
    console.log('First Controller...........');
    console.log(MySharingService.saveData(dataTobeSaved)); //Pass the data here
}

function Second($scope, MySharingService) {
    console.log('Second Controller..........');
    console.log(MySharingService.getData());
}
```

Comment: in the function First how can I make sure the function invokes just I am leaving the page? I want it to be the last action in the page.

Comment: On a fresh controller change.. The new controller will be executing. So once you get to the new contorller it will access the data from the service.

Answer (score 1):

AngularJS emits the event `$locationChangeStart` before the location is changed, which you can listen to with `scope.$on("$locationChangeStart", function (...) { ... })`. See [the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location). If it's not a location change but only a (sub)view change you could listen to that scope's `$destroy` event in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Each state has an onExit,OnEnter callback function. So you can call your service function onExit.

```
$stateProvider.state("contacts", {
  template: '<h1>{{title}}</h1>',
  resolve: { title: 'My Contacts' },
  controller: function($scope, title){
    $scope.title = 'My Contacts';
  },
  onEnter: function(title){
    if(title){ ... do something ... }
  },
  onExit: function(title){
    if(title){ ... do something ... }
  }
})
```

Comment: I think he is not using ui-router... Or did not mention it.